# No se puede abrir 'nombre_archivo': Archivo no encontrado (/ruta/hasta/el/archivo)

Tags: vscode

Compilo un programa con `gcc`. Desde `VSCode` abro un archivo de fuentes, y establezco un punto de parada.

A continuación, en la máquina destino, lanzo el `gdbserver` con los argumentos adecuados. El depurador se ejecuta y queda a la espera de conexiones.

Desde `VSCode`, vista de depuración, lanzo la depuración remota. Todo correcto, se conecta al `gdbserver`.

En el momento en el que se alcanza el punto de interrupción, el archivo de código fuente **se cierra**, y el `VSCode` muestra la *ventanita* con el aviso:

> No se puede abrir `nombre-del-archivo`: Archivo no encontrado (file:///ruta/completa/hasta/el/archivo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy compilando desde una VM, donde el directorio del proyecto está correctamente compartido entre Windows (anfitrión) y Linux (invitado). Desde Linux, la carpeta compartida (como se muestra en la imagen) es `/media/sf_D_Drive`.

Por supuesto, el archivo que supuestamente **no existe** está presente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿ Como consigo que `VSCode` no me cierre el archivo fuente, ni muestre la ventanida de error, al llegar al punto de interrupción ?

#### EDITO

Me acabo de dar cuenta del problema: compilo desde la VM, pero el `VSCode` lo estoy ejecutando desde la máquina anfitrión; el ejecutable tiene las rutas relativas a la VM, mientras que las rutas en Windows (anfitrión) son distintas.

Ruta en Linux: `/media/sf_D_DRIVE/CMS/Subversion/CORE_5G/src/com`

Ruta en Windows: `D:\CMS\Subversion\CORE_5G\src\com`

Archivo `.vscode\launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdbserver) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/CFGP_bin_ConfigParam_cos",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "c:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "214.25.250.7:10000",
      "targetArchitecture": "x86",
      "linux": {
        "MIMode": "gdb"
      },
      "windows": {
        "MIMode": "gdb"
      },
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes configurar la ruta de las fuentes usando `sourceFileMap`, como se explica aqui:

[Localizar archivos de fuentes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_locate-source-files) (En inglés).

Debes añadir lo siguiente en `launch.json`:

```
"sourceFileMap": { 
     "/media/sf_D_DRIVE/CMS/Subversion/": "D:/CMS/Subversion/" 
}
```

Tu `launch.json` quedará asi:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.  
  // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos  
  // Para más información, visite:   go.microsoft.com/fwlink/…  
"version":"0.2.0",
   "configurations":[  
      {  
         "name":"(gdbserver) Launch",
         "type":"cppdbg",
         "request":"launch",
         "program":"${workspaceFolder}/bin/CFGP_bin_ConfigParam_cos",
         "args":[  

         ],
         "stopAtEntry":false,
         "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
         "environment":[  

         ],
         "externalConsole":true,
         "MIMode":"gdb",
         "miDebuggerPath":"c:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
         "miDebuggerServerAddress":"214.25.250.7:10000",
         "targetArchitecture":"x86",
         "linux":{  
            "MIMode":"gdb"
         },
         "windows":{  
            "MIMode":"gdb",
            "sourceFileMap":{  
               "/media/sf_D_DRIVE/CMS/Subversion/":"D:/CMS/Subversion/"
            }
         },
         "setupCommands":[  
            {  
               "description":"Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
               "text":"-enable-pretty-printing",
               "ignoreFailures":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```