# Configurar QT Creator para depuración remota

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, gdb

Estoy tratando de configurar el IDE de Qt, "Qt Creator" versión 4.8.0

Estoy desarrollando sobre Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 bionic y el dispositivo remoto para el que estoy desarrollando es un iMX6, arquitectura "armv7l", de la empresa ICNEXUS con Debian 3.10.53

Mi host de desarrollo está conectado al dispositivo por ethernet. La comunicación entre ambos es correcta. Puedo ejecutar de forma remota sin problemas. La aplicación se ejecuta en el dispositivo sin problema y todos los `qDebug` se ven en la consola de salida de mi IDE.

El problema que tengo está en configurar el entorno de desarrollo para depurar de forma remota con GDB.

He instalado en el host remoto (el dispositivo iMX6) el gdbserver y en Qt Creator tengo la siguiente configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen en la que se muestra cómo añado el depurador gdb de "Poky 1.7" para depurar sobre el sistema remoto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra  se la configuración de los compiladores. Funcionan perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se especifica la versión de Qt que tengo que usar en el desarrollo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta ultima imagen se ve la configuración del kit que uso en el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta es donde tengo más dudas. Es la parte en la que se puede configurar la depuración remota. Según la documentación es donde se deben añadir los comandos opcionales o los necesarios para especificar las rutas de los archivos a depurar.

Con todo esto configurado, cuando trato de depurar de forma remota recibo el siguiente mensaje:

```
16:56:54: Checking available ports...
16:56:54: Found 101 free ports.
16:56:54: Starting gdbserver...
16:56:54: Debugging starts
stdin: is not a tty
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 192.168.1.47
Process /opt/PegasusApp/bin/PegasusApp created; pid = 5659
Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.Could not load shared library 
symbols for 77 libraries, e.g. /usr/lib/libversionControl.so.1.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que entiendo del mensaje, me está diciendo que GDB no es capaz de encontrar las librerías que he creado para el proyecto y que debería usar los comandos `set solib-search-path` o equivalente `set sysroot`.

El problema es que no se qué ruta he de asignarle exactamente. Como podéis ver en las imágenes anteriores le he indicado la ruta donde se copian las librerías en el host remoto `/usr/lib`. Pero no se si se especifica o he de indicarle la IP del dispositivo, ni qué formato debería usar para ello. También he probado a indicarle la ruta de la carpeta donde generan las librerías en local antes de hacer el deploy.

¿Alguien sabe cómo he de configurarlo exactamente? ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos. Si hay alguna información que falte o no esté claro estaré encantado de aclararlo tan pronto como sea posible.

Comment: Prueba colocando en `set solib-search-path` **la ruta de la maquina de desarrollo** en la que buscar las librerías; en mi caso, `/home/trauma/Proyecto/Builds/libs`.

Comment: @Trauma En parte me ha ayudado pero aun no he terminado de solucionarlo. Tras poner la ruta a las librerías que hay en mi máquina de desarrollo han empezado a aparecer mensajes de diferentes librerías que no encontraba. Algunas de Qt otras de la arquitectura de la máquina destino. He ido poniendo las rutas necesarias. Ahora cuando intento depurar solo sale un mensaje en una ventana emergente que me dice *The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.* Sin más explicación... Estoy un poco atascado con este tema.

Comment: Intenta poniendo el `sysroot`, la carpeta en la maquina de desarrollo; en mi caso, `/opt/SDK/sysroot`. Eso último ... malo. ¿ Si lo ejecutas **sin el gdbserver** en la máquina remota, funciona bien ?

Comment: @Trauma Si desinstalo el gdbserver me salta el error indicando que no ha podido encontrar gdbserver.

Comment: Con sysroot me vuelven los errores de antes aunque mantenga las rutas...

Comment: Si claro :-) Me refería a si lo ejecutabas en la máquina remota en una sesión *ssh* o *telnet*. Lo de `The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system` no suena bien ...

Comment: @Trauma el caso es que el programa que ejecuto en la máquina remota funciona bien. Lo estoy usando en producción. Por lo que descarto que sea problema de la aplicación.

Comment: Ah, @Trauma la conexión se hace a través de ssh.

Comment: Pufff ... Pues no se que mas decirte, En mi configuración, con un QtCreator mas antiguo, funciona bien la depuración en remoto. Solo una cosa: el `set solib...` lo tengo puesto en `Additional Attach Commands`, **no** en `Additional Startup Commands`. Y **no** tengo puesto `info sharedlibrary`. Por lo demás, parece que lo tienes todo bien :-(

Comment: Último comentario: si no lo consigues con el QtCreator, te recomiendo el [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Aparte de que te va a permitir configuraciones **imposibles** con el QtCreator (yo estoy depurando en remoto desde una máquina que **no tiene el SDK instalado**), se configura mediante archivos de texto, con lo que es mucho mas fácil encontrar cosas (e incluso [publicar preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/213502/19610) aquí). Por otra parte, no usa *proyectos*, por lo que el cambio puede ser ... traumático.